# How can I backup and restore Database file in Oracle db?

Tags: database, oracle, backup, restore

I am a beginner in oracle DB 19C windows64. I have a database file that I want to restore it in oracle DB. Similarly, I want to take backup of that database file in my PC.

Comment: RMAN - Oracle Recovery MANager is the tool you need to learn. C:\>rman target /

Comment: I have seen few articles about RMAN but it couldn't help me. Can you provide some good resource of RMAN so that I can study about it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/administration.html

Comment: The first thing you need to understand is that if you have an oracle database, you do not have "a" (as in "one") database file.  An oracle database is made up of many files.Backup and recovery is not a trivial subject.  I would _not_ depend on some anonymous blog articles.  Go to the source:  Start with https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/index.html.   And also the actual REFERENCE MANUAL: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/rcmrf/index.html